# MediaWiki VisualEditor textcolor

Tags: mediawiki, textcolor, visual-editor

I'm trying to extend the VisualEditor by adding custom functionality.

It was pretty easy to add stuff which is realized with a single HTML-tag without parameters. But now I try to add textcolor. I tried to replicate the LanguageAnnotation as that's pretty similar (using span lang=.. while I want span style=color:..).

But it looks like there are a lot more things which I have to change here & I don't understand.

I'd be very grateful for any kind of help here.

Edit: To provide more information: Currently I am trying to replicate the .toDomElements function which I struggle with because I can not find the place where to modify the exact tag syntax (style instead of lang).

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ("add textcolor"? as in a button to set the textcolor attribute, or what?) and what have you done so far?

Comment: @Nemo that's exactly what I wanted. I also wrote what I was currently doing into the question. The problem is solved by now tho. I'll write down everything I did when I'll work on that project the next time.

Comment: Nice, I'll wait for your solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if it's the best possible solution, but I've managed this problem by replicating the *LanguageAnnotatation*, including the widget-system (I chose it because it was the closest one to what I wanted to accomplish as it uses CSS and the *span*-tag).

I've replicated the following classes, adjusting the attributes (language has lang and dir attributes, my color-annotation only the color attribute):

- ve.ce.TextColorAnnotation.js
- ve.dm.TextColorAnnotation.js
- ve.ui.TextColorContextItem.js
- ve.ui.TextColorSearchDialog.js
- ve.ui.TextColorInspector.js
- ve.ui.TextColorInspectorTool.js
- ve.ui.TextColorSearchWidget.js
- ve.ui.TextColorInputWidget.js
- ve.ui.TextColorResultWidget.js

It works pretty good imo. The only problem I see right now (and which I am working on next) is that with this implementation, text (or background)-color can only be applied to text, but not to tables (only when marking the text inside a cell).

Comment: Could you please share your solution?

Comment: Yeah I can but I won't have access to it for around ~10 days as I am on holiday.

Comment: This looks amazing. We are facing similar issues and would really be happy to see that code. 
Have a nice holiday.

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot about this. Here's the source: 
https://www.pastefs.com/pid/2913
I guess that's everything for the textcolor solution. If I forgot something, let me know. Also don't forget to add the files to the VisualEditor.php